# ExternalAcessory Framework for iOS: using the iphone as a usb device

Tags: ios, ios5, external-accessory

I'm looking into the iOS sdk for examples of the ExternalAccessory framework to use the iphone/ipad as an USB device that can be plugged into a PC or Mac and present as external device (like a midi controller or something else)

The App i want to create requires connecting to a host (PC or Mac) the iphone via USB or bluetooth and present to the host a functionality. How can i implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have an easier time connecting via WiFi. You need to be part of the Apple Made for iPhone program, which is not easy to get into, to use Bluetooth or the dock connector to talk to peripherals. There's no such restriction on the use of WiFi. Also, you'll find a lot more helpful examples of connecting via WiFi on the web.

Comment: but isn't the made for iphone program to create devices that are certified to connect *to* the iphone, and apps that connect to them? my plan is for the iphone be the device itself

Comment: Yes, but if you're not a member of the MFi program, you can't use the APIs required to talk to custom devices via BlueTooth or serial port. Why not use WiFi?

Answer (score 0):

CoreMIDI is the appropriate API for emulating a MIDI device, which may be possible over USB using Apples Camera Connection kit.